# Indecomposable G-equivariant vector bundles

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quantum-groups

I am reading the paper "The representation ring of the quantum double of a finite group" by Witherspoon. In Chapter 2 we define a G-equivariant vector bundle on a finite G-set $X$, as a collection of finite dimensional vector spaces $\{U_x\}_{x\in X}$, with a representation of $G$ on $\bigoplus_{x}U_x$ such that $U_x \cdot g=U_{x^g}$.

We then decompose the $\bigoplus_{x}U_x=\bigoplus_{\sigma}U_\sigma$ for each $G$-orbit $\sigma$ on $X$, with $U_\sigma=\bigoplus_{x\in \sigma}U_x$. Now I think I see why these $U_\sigma$ are $kG$-submodules of $\bigoplus_{x}U_x$, since the $$U_\sigma \cdot g=\bigoplus_{x\in \sigma}U_x\cdot g=\bigoplus_{x\in \sigma}U_{x^g}=\bigoplus_{x\in \sigma}U_x=U_\sigma$$
It is claimed these $U_\sigma$ are the indecomposable G-equivariant vector bundles on $X$. But by the definition above, a vector bundle on $X$ is a collection of vector spaces, one for each $x\in X$. But these $U_\sigma$ only have vector spaces defined over the elements in the orbit: $x\in \sigma\subset X$. Is it implicitly assumed we take trivial/zero vector spaces over the remaining points in $X\backslash \sigma$? Otherwise I don't see how these objects can be called vector bundles on $X$.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think that's what it says, yes. Indeed, if you consider $U_\sigma$ as a bundle this way, then $U=\bigoplus_\sigma U_\sigma$ so it is indecomposable if and only if all $U_\sigma$'s but one are $0$, which coincides with the result stated that there is a correspondance between the pairs and the indecomposable bundles

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. So just to be explicit, we have $U_\sigma=(\bigoplus_{x\in \sigma}U_x) \oplus (\bigoplus_{x\in X\backslash \sigma} 0)$. Then, as you say, it basically just works with the results that follow.

Comment: A second point/question: is it correct to regard the representation in the definition of the vector bundle as a right representation i.e. an group anti-homomorphism/ or a right $kG$-module. Since it is acting from the right on the vector spaces. Just as I had not come across these before, and again nothing is said about this, and it is just referred to in paper as a representation...